# Error when activating IIS-feature IIS-NetFxExtensibility 4.5

Tags: iis, wix

I have programmed a Bootstrapper-project with WiX 3.8 in which some IIS-features like IIS-NetFxExtensibility 4.5 are activated while the installation-process.
When the installation gets to the point, where IIS-NetFxExtensibility 4.5 should be activated, i'm always getting that error:

```
[0C5C:0E10][2014-11-17T11:11:46]i301: Applying execute package: IIS_NetFxExtensibility45, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\00043DEBDB9EC3D2545AA23EF6F8F43105D677E0\Dism.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\00043DEBDB9EC3D2545AA23EF6F8F43105D677E0\Dism.exe" /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-NetFxExtensibility45'
[0C5C:0E10][2014-11-17T11:11:48]e000: Error 0x80070032: Process returned error: 0x32
[0C5C:0E10][2014-11-17T11:11:48]e000: Error 0x80070032: Failed to execute EXE package.
[0994:0694][2014-11-17T11:11:48]e000: Error 0x80070032: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[0994:0694][2014-11-17T11:11:48]i319: Applied execute package: IIS_NetFxExtensibility45, result: 0x80070032, restart: None
[0994:0694][2014-11-17T11:11:48]e000: Error 0x80070032: Failed to execute EXE package.
```

I'm using the following lines in my WXS-file for activation:

```
    <ExePackage Id='IIS_NetFxExtensibility45'
                DisplayName='Installing IIS: IIS-NetFxExtensibility 4.5'
                PerMachine='yes'
                SourceFile='.\Resources\Dism.exe'
                InstallCommand='/Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:IIS-NetFxExtensibility45'>
    </ExePackage>
```

Can anybody tell me, what's going wrong?
Other features like IIS_WebserverRole are no problem.
Maybe ASP.Net missing?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The point ist, that some features are dependent upon the feature NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45.
Before all these features NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45 has to be activated.
That's all :)

Nice to know:
If You try to activate one of the complicated features by commandline, You can get here a more significant advice.